# How I can emulate a big endian platform on a x86?

Tags: architecture, emulation

I need to get a big endian platform to develop with `gcc` and `g++`, what is a solution for that? I know that the SPARC is one of those big endian architectures, but I have no idea what OSs can run on it and how to emulate a SPARC machine under Linux; I also should note that I need any big endian that I can emulate on an X86 but with `g++` available on it.

Comment: Debian supports `sparc`.

Comment: @jordanm yes, but apparently is a port with not that much effort ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why Sparc specifically? ARM or MIPS is easier to emulate or to get in hardware, both are bi-endian, and both are supported by Linux in either endianness.

There doesn't seem to be a well-maintained ARM big-endian port, your best bet for ARM seems to be the old [Debian NSLU2 port](http://www.cyrius.com/debian/nslu2/unpack/). For MIPS you have the [MIPS port](http://www.debian.org/ports/mips/).

[QEMU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QEMU) can emulate all of these CPUs.

Comment: there is nothing special about the SPARC, it's just the first big endian architecture that came to my mind. the problem with ARM and MIPS is that I couldn't find a good OS, I'm trying that debian mips.

Answer (score 3):

I think [QEMU](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page) can emulate Sparc under Linux. Also you can use Debian as guest os, because sparc is one of its supported platforms. There is [guide here](http://www.aurel32.net/info/debian_sparc_qemu.php) .

Comment: any other big endian platform that is available for virtualization ?

Comment: I suggest you to look at debian ports table to see, what architectures it does support and what architectures are big and little endian: http://www.debian.org/ports/ . ARM and MIPS are another feasible emulation targets, while both are really bi-endian, OS packages and compilers try to stick to one endianess.

Answer (score 2):

As an aside, maybe it would be easier for you to simply get a SPARC or HPPA from ebay, they're cheap nowadays. Both are supported by Linux and BSDs and do a wonderful job. HPPAs (select models) are biendian, maybe that'll help you more.